# Flex end is not moving element

Tags: css, flexbox, polymer-1.0

```
<dom-module id="catChat-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      .app-title{
        display: flex;
      },
      .account-icon{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-drawer-panel>
      <paper-header-panel drawer>
        <paper-toolbar>
          <div>Application</div>
        </paper-toolbar>
      </paper-header-panel>
      <paper-header-panel main>
        <paper-toolbar>
          <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
          <div class="app-title" flex><span>Cat Chat</span></div>

          <div class="account-icon">
          <iron-icon icon="account-circle"></iron-icon>
          <span><!--number of people--></span>
          </div>

        </paper-toolbar>
        <div>MainContent</div>
      </paper-header-panel>
        </paper-drawer-panel>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'catChat-app',

      properties: {
        prop1: {
          type: String,
          value: 'catChat-app',
        },
      },

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I am trying to use flex box to separate the app title and the account icon.  I would like them to go to each end, this is my current attempt and it is failing. Could someone help explain what I am doing wrong with flexbox?

Comment: justify-content is a property for a flex parent/container: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a wrapping container element and apply the below flex styles, like the following (abridged example):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="app-title"><span>Cat Chat</span></div>
    <div class="account-icon"><span><!--number of people--></span></div>
</div>
```

Note: In this case your child elements do not need `display:flex`

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/9udb0ff3/

Comment: It did not have any effect :(

Comment: try comparing what you have to the attached fiddle! (you can see it working in action)

Comment: I got it to work, but I had to give .container a width of 100%